# Can't return a list of correct values if it has negative values

Tags: python

```
def double(lst: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    ans = []
    for i in range(1, len(lst)+1):
        ans.append(2 * i)
    return ans
```

if the list is [-2],
it returns [2] without a negative sign

Comment: You aren't actually using any of the values in `lst`.

Comment: you are trying to perform `2 * i` which is doubling value but expecting to get absolute value i.e. `-2` to `2`.

Comment: your just multiplying the index position plus one, of each element in list by 2. `[1*2, 2*2, 3*2]`. So in your one example your list has one element at index 0 so I will be come `0+1` then multipleid by 2. I.E `1 * 2 = 2`

Comment: It's the first index (1) of the list * 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments you are using the index poistion +1 not its value. You could write this much more succient with a list comprehension like

```py
from typing import List


def double(lst: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    return [l * 2 for l in lst]


print(double([-2, 5, -4]))
```

This essentially takes every element of your `lst` and stores the value in l on each iteration and multiplys it by 2 building all the results into a new list and returning that.

**output**

```
[-4, 10, -8]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using any values from the list that you are passing as parameter to the double function. you are just running your loop up to the length of your list & doubling the index of that list. So, in current format, you will never get a negative sign.

You have to change both the iteration of your loop starting from 0 to `len(lst)`
and you need to append `2*lst[i]` instead of `2*i`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Python where we happily don't have to bother with indices

```
def double(lst: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    return [2 * item for item in lst]
```

Comment: Could do with more explaining to what the code is actually doing

Answer (score 1):

`for i in range(1, len(lst)+1))` is iterating over the index of `lst` not the value of the `lst`, so changing it to `for i in lst` would iterate the value.

You can get same result using `list`, `map`, and `lambda` function:

```
def double(lst: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    return list(map(lambda i: 2 * i, lst))

print(double([-2, 2, 3, 7, 18, -1, 0]))

# [-4, 4, 6, 14, 36, -2, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, `i` was the place the loop was in between the numbers `1` and `len(lst)+1`. This needs to be changed to `for i in lst:` as below,

```
def double(lst: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    ans = []
    for i in lst:
        ans.append(2 * i)
    return ans
```

Or `ans.append(2 * lst[i])` as below

```
def double(lst: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    ans = []
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        ans.append(2 * lst[i])
    return ans
```